# Trying to get a tooltip shown in eventRender from the fullcalendar documentation

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, tooltip, popper.js

Im working on a fullCalendar overview interface Using: Flask-python on server and html jinja2 js on client side.

Right now i am trying to create a tooltip on hover or click using tooltip.js.

I have a bug that drives me to the popper.js index.

here is my basic js:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: ['dayGrid'],
            defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',

            eventRender: function(info) {
             var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
                    title: "info.event.extendedProps.description",
                    placement: 'top',
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    container: 'body'
                  });
        },
        events: {{hour}}           

    });

    calendar.render();

  });
```

From what i saw, le eventRender is called, if i mouseover the tooltip div is created BUT i got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: a is not a constructor
at g.value (index.js:246)
at index.js:381
```

which is referencing this:

```
this.popperInstance = new Popper(
  reference,
  tooltipNode,
  this._popperOptions
);
```

Comment: I just came across the same error in the same way and my search results found this thread. If I figure this out, I'll let you know.  Else, keep me posted too.

Comment: You can see a working version using tooltip.js here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZZdgMb?&editable=true&editors=001 . There is a link to it already from the fullCalendar documented at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender . This version does not produce the error. I suggest you compare it to your version (both the code itself, and the libraries you're loading, and their version numbers) and ensure you haven't missed anything important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case someone else runs into this -- if you're not using Bootstrap, it's likely due to the order in which you're loading Popper and Tooltip.

Popper.js is a dependency of Tooltip.js, so it has to be loaded before Tooltip.js. `a is not a constructor` because `a` is `undefined`, and if you look at the source code, `a` represents Popper.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was a import conflict between boostrap and popper js,
 to resolve it i change the framework i am using materialize to avoid the problem as i couldn't get it working with boostrap js 
(i think boostrap has his own tooltip and popper function that might have been the problem)